# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided - NodeJS error

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the error "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided." when using `res.render('index',{filmes: filmes})`. the variable filmes is getting data from SQL (code in the img below). I also tried to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filmes))` but didn't worked.

See my code:
[My code from routers (server.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTaH.png)

Comment: when you are using render it means you are using a render engine to create html output, So you need to determine that engine. But in your case you can just response the ```JSON``` object like this: ```res.json(filmes)``` or ```res.send(filmes)```.

Comment: Hi :)  Just a tiny nitpick. Your question is already quite good, but it can still be improved. It would be better if you could edit your question and include your code example as code block instead of a picture. You can do that by putting your code into the text field, marking it and then clicking the `{}` icon on top of your text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a view engine in server.js

try ejs for example

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

make sure to install ejs

```
npm install ejs --save
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, really helpful! 
I have one more question, regarding the path. Adding my path, which is 'Public' (to find the index page), I get the error 'Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory', but I see the file in the same path that I'm getting the error.  I tried to re-install all npm's but still getting the error. Even changing the path name to 'views' I get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @GabrielDonada create a folder named views in the root directory and add your index.ejs to this folder